# ReadTimeOutError MongoConnector

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm currently getting a Read Time Out Error whilst using MongoConnector, I've tried restarting ElasticSearch but I still can't get it to work for some reason.

```
ConnectionFailed: ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=10))
2018-04-21 13:36:04,655 [ERROR] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:678 - OplogThread: Failed during dump collection cannot recover! Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, replicaset=u'rs0'), u'local'), u'oplog.rs')
2018-04-21 13:36:05,652 [ERROR] mongo_connector.connector:398 - MongoConnector: OplogThread <OplogThread(Thread-3, started 139952213964544)> unexpectedly stopped! Shutting down
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-23-11 ~]$ cat /home/ec2-user/mongo-connector.log | less

    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 309, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % timeout_value)
ReadTimeoutError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
2018-04-21 13:36:38,652 [WARNING] elasticsearch:88 - POST http://localhost:9200/_refresh [status:N/A request:10.011s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 95, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 333, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 389, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 309, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % timeout_value)
ReadTimeoutError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
2018-04-21 13:36:49,664 [WARNING] elasticsearch:88 - POST http://localhost:9200/_refresh [status:N/A request:10.011s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 95, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 333, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 389, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 309, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % timeout_value)
ReadTimeoutError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
```

Comment: did you find a solution for your issue?